# Filtering by category in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to implement filters by category in my React app.
They work when I check one category.
The problems I can't solve right now - only one filter is being applied. So if I choose `1` and `All` only `1` will apply. And another problem which is present is that when I uncheck filters they are not reseting.

All help with these issues will be much appreciated.

In the first issue I assume I need to turn filters to array or object so that I can store multiple values?

Filters.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

interface stopsFilterProps {
    setCurrentFilter: (stops: string | number) => void
}

const StopsFilter: React.SFC<stopsFilterProps> = ({ setCurrentFilter }: stopsFilterProps) => {
    return (
        <div className="stops-filters">
            <ul className="stops-filter__list">
                <li className="stops-filter__list-item">
                    <label className="stops-filter__list-label" htmlFor="all">All</label>
                    <input id="all" type="checkbox" onChange={() => setCurrentFilter('All')} />
                </li>
                <li className="stops-filter__list-item">
                    <label className="stops-filter__list-label" htmlFor="zero">0</label> 
                    <input id="zero" type="checkbox" onChange={() => setCurrentFilter(0)} />
                </li>
                <li className="stops-filter__list-item">
                    <label className="stops-filter__list-label" htmlFor="one">1</label>
                    <input id="one" type="checkbox" onChange={() => setCurrentFilter(1)} />
                </li>
                <li className="stops-filter__list-item">
                    <label className="stops-filter__list-label" htmlFor="two">2</label>
                    <input id="two" type="checkbox" onChange={() => setCurrentFilter(2)} />
                </li>
                <li className="stops-filter__list-item">
                    <label className="stops-filter__list-label" htmlFor="three">3</label>
                    <input id="three" type="checkbox" onChange={() => setCurrentFilter(3)} />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default StopsFilter;
```

Its' parent component

```
import React from 'react';

import StopsFilter from '../../blocks/Filters/StopsFilter'

interface stopsFilterComponentProps {
    setFilter: (stops: string | number) => void
}

const StopsFilterComponent: React.SFC<stopsFilterComponentProps> = ({setFilter}:stopsFilterComponentProps) => {
    function setCurrentFilter (stops: string | number) {
        setFilter(stops);
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <StopsFilter setCurrentFilter={setCurrentFilter}></StopsFilter>
        </div>
    )
}
export default StopsFilterComponent;
```

And in App.tsx

```
const App: React.SFC = () => {
  const [stopsFilter, setFilter] = useState<string | number>('All')

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="filters-holder">
        <StopsFilterComponent setFilter={(stops: string | number) => setFilter(stops)}></StopsFilterComponent>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: looks like typescript, might wanna include that in the tags if that's the case

Comment: Your filter is designed for only one setting (`setCurrentFilter`). You would need to expand that or change it to accept multiple filters or turn on and off a given filter and update the behavior of how it works to deal with that. (more than just a small tweak)

Comment: I'm not sure how to expend setCurrentFilter. Should I make it so it takes an array as argument or ?